# Google Sheet Script - Unsuccessful Email Automation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to put together a script which cycles through a two dimensional range from a spreadsheet; when the criteria is met (in this case, when training is a month and a week respectively before needing renewed) an email should be sent.

I was able to achieve this when the script only had to cycle through one column with several rows; however now that I'm attempting to cycle through several columns and several rows, the script is running without error, but the data is not triggering an email to be sent.

A smaller version of the script I'm attempting to use is displayed below, though the original is much more extensive in an attempt to cover the large range of data. The script not present here is a repetition of the 'Column' sections for each individual column that needs to be taken into consideration.

```
function trainingReminder() {
//For testing purposes
//You can view the log by typing CMD+ENTER (CTRL + E) after you run the script.
Logger.log(msg);

// grab the Google Sheet object
var googleSheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// activates the first sheet
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(googleSheets.getSheets()[0]);
// grabs the sheet
var currentSheet = googleSheets.getActiveSheet();

// find the last row
var lastRow = currentSheet.getLastRow();

// The first row starts at row 2 to account for headers
var startRow = 2;

//**************************************************************//
//                        Column AU                             //
//**************************************************************//

// get AU column data (Training Name)
var range = currentSheet.getRange(2,48,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var remainingDays = range.getValues();

// get AR column data (Employee Names)
//range = currentSheet.getRange(2, 45, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);

var columnAR = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop column AU (Training Name) (1 Month)
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
if(daysLeft == 30) {
// Checks to see if a cell value in column AU equals 30
var employeeName = columnAR[i][0];
msg = msg + "Don't Forget: "+employeeName+"'s "+employeeTraining+" is due in
"+daysLeft+" days.\n";
warning_count++;
}
}

// Loop column AU (Training Name) (1 Week)
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
if(daysLeft == 7) {
// Checks to see if a cell value in column AU equals 7
var employeeName = columnAR[i][0];
var employeeTraining = range.getValue(1,48);

msg = msg + "Don't Forget: "+employeeName+"'s "+employeeTraining+" is due a week.\n";
warning_count++;
}
}

//**************************************************************//
//                       Column AV                              //
//**************************************************************//

// get AV column data (Training Name)
var range = currentSheet.getRange(2,49,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var remainingDays = range.getValues();

// get AR column data (Employee Names)
//range = currentSheet.getRange(2, 45, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);

var columnAR = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop column AV (Training Name) (1 Month)
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
if(daysLeft == 30) {
// Checks to see if a cell value in column AV equals 30
var employeeName = columnAR[i][0];
var employeeTraining = range.getValue(1,49)
msg = msg + "Don't Forget: "+employeeName+"'s "+employeeTraining+" is due in "+daysLeft+" days.\n";
warning_count++;
}
}

// Loop column AV (Training Name) (1 Week)
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
if(daysLeft == 7) {
// Checks to see if a cell value in column AV equals 7
var employeeName = columnAR[i][0];
var employeeTraining = range.getValue(1,49);

msg = msg + "Don't Forget: "+employeeName+"'s "+employeeTraining+" is due a week.\n";
warning_count++;
}
}

//**************************************************************//
//                       Column AW                              //
//**************************************************************//

// get AW column data (Training Name)
var range = currentSheet.getRange(2,50,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var remainingDays = range.getValues();

// get AR column data (Employee Names)
//range = currentSheet.getRange(2, 45, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);

var columnAR = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";

// Loop column AW (Training Name) (1 Month)
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
if(daysLeft == 30) {
// Checks to see if a cell value in column AW equals 30
var employeeName = columnAR[i][0];
var employeeTraining = range.getValue(1,50)

msg = msg + "Don't Forget: "+employeeName+"'s "+employeeTraining+" is due in "+daysLeft+" days.\n";
warning_count++;
}
}

// Loop column AW (Training Name) (1 Week)
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
if(daysLeft == 7) {
// Checks to see if a cell value in column AW equals 7
var employeeName = columnAR[i][0];
var employeeTraining = range.getValue(1,50);

msg = msg + "Don't Forget: "+employeeName+"'s "+employeeTraining+" is due a week.\n";
warning_count++;
}
}

// Loop column CG (Training Name) (1 Week)
for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
var daysLeft = remainingDays[i][0];
if(daysLeft == 7) {
// Checks to see if a cell value in column CG equals 7
var employeeName = columnAR[i][0];
var employeeTraining = range.getValue(1,86);

msg = msg + "Don't Forget: "+employeeName+"'s "+employeeTraining+" is due a week.\n";
warning_count++;
}
}

if(warning_count) {
MailApp.sendEmail("example@email.com",
"Training Reminder", msg);
}
};
```

I realise there's probably something very obvious to anyone competent with writing scripts, but unfortunately I'm not there yet with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's your CONDITION for an email to be sent? Check that since it's not being met that's why nothing's happening. Add a logger inside to check if that if statement is being accessed inside or not.

Comment: The condition is intended to be that once a particular form of training is 30 days (and subsequently 7 days) away from needing renewal in my spreadsheet, that a reminded email is sent. I used the exact same code for a similar project which worked with the same condition, so I can't figure out why it's not working in this instance.